# String concatenation in PHP

Tags: php, echo

Is it possible to send some text message with an echo?

I'm looking for something like: `if($xml) echo $xml+"hello world;`

This is my PHP:

```
[...]curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);

    $xml = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close ($curl);
 if($xml) echo $xml; 
?>
```

Comment: Uh what? Do you mean you need another function? Also, the `+` operator is for mathematical operations, the `.` operator is for concatenation, so unless you plan on adding the mathematical value stored in `$xml` to "hello world"...

Comment: Does anybody use Google these days? Or official manuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.=` to append a string to a variable:

```
$xml .= 'Hello World';
```

If you just want to echo $xml followed by "Hello World", why not:

```
if ($xml) {
  echo $xml;
  echo 'Hello World';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate in PHP.

`if($xml) { echo $xml . "hello world"; }`