# How do I pull in text and add a set of characters to the end of that user's text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Example:

```
if: $text="youtube.com/video"
```

I want to add something like "example" to the end of that text.

making it:

```
youtube.com/videoexample
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688184/string-concatenation-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
$text .= "example";
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for something like this ih php:

```
<?php
if( $text == "youtube.com/video" )
{
    $text = $text . 'example';
}
?>
```

`.` is concatenation operator that joins its operand strings.